# jQuery does not apply offset on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to apply a JS function on two events: window.resize and document.ready. The second one just won't work.

When I load the website I want this function to execute and apply the CSS. This is the last JS code before the

I've tried many JS events, but no success.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", footerMargin);

$( document ).ready(function() {   footerMargin();   });

function footerMargin() {
    var offset = $( ".section-item--coming-soon").offset();
    var novaVar = Math.round(offset.top);
    var leftVar = Math.round($( ".footer--section").offset.left);

    var heightComingSoon = $( ".section-item--coming-soon").height();

    var overall = novaVar + heightComingSoon + 75;


    $( ".footer--section").offset({ top: overall, left: leftVar });

}
```

Comment: The function `footerMargin()` is being called on `document.ready`. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/ox31ryoo/1/). So it's something to do with your code. Could you provide an example?

Comment: please show the `html`

Answer (score 0):

Upon setting value to `leftVar` you are using `$( ".footer--section").offset.left` instead of `$( ".footer--section").offset().left`.

This `Math.round($( ".footer--section").offset.left)` will return `NaN`.

Change that to:

```
var leftVar = Math.round($( ".footer--section").offset().left);
```